# Replace html text with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I have this html:

```
<div class="field-item even">0,00 €</div>
```

I have this function to replace some text, **which works fine:**

```
$('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace('0,00 €', '<span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span>');  

});
```

But I need to change the function to this, **which doesn't work at all** (no errors in console.log):

```
$('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace('>0,00 €<', '><span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span><');  

});
```

As you can see I just added some '<' and '>'.

Just in case you want to know why I need to do this: I need to avoid the function to replace values like '150,00 €', '90,00 €' and so. I need it to replace the value '0,00 €', only this one.

Comment: Wouldn't a regex make more sense?

Comment: What will happen, when you write `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;`instead of `>`? I meant the single ones, not these which are a part of the html tag

Comment: @reporter - nothing would happen because that's trying to match an HTML entity with an actual closing tag bracket.

Comment: your right, I oversaw the replace method^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with a regex

```
return oldhtml.replace(/^0,00 €$/, '<span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very unclear why you would ever need to do this, but:

The problem is that the `>` and `<` are not part of the HTML **contents** of the `.field-info` tag, they *are* the tags. Calling `.html()` does not return the tags which wrap the current node.

Given this HTML fragment in the DOM...

```
<div class="field-name-commerce-price">
  <div class="field-item even">0,00 €</div>
</div>
```

Using `$(.field-item).html()` will return `0,00 €`, the HTML contents of the tag selected. There are no `>` or `<` to match.

If you want to replace part of the tags themselves, you can go to the element's parent. Using `$('.field-item').parent().html()` will return the nested element's HTML, `<div class="field-item even">0,00 €</div>` which will match your `replace`.

Try the following:

```
$('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.parent().replace('>0,00 €<', '><span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span><');  

});
```

--

RE: Your updates

> Just in case you want to know why I need to do this: I need to avoid the function to replace values like '150,00 €', '90,00 €' and so. I need it to replace the value '0,00 €', only this one.

Then, using `>` and `<` as delimiters on your replace string is the wrong solution.
Either use a simple equality check...

```
if ('0,00 €' == $('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').text()) {
  $('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').html('<span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span>'); 
}
```

Or, use a regular expression, and anchor your search pattern with `^` and `$`, or add wound boundaries:

```
$('.field-name-commerce-price .field-item').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace(/\b0,00 €\b/, '<span style="font-size:13px;">No price</span>');  
});
```